# How can I catch errors here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I have router and two acync fetching from DB. What is the correct way to catch errors here?

```
router.get('/restaurant/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    var current_restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({restaurantId: req.params.id}).exec();
    var products = await Product.find({restaurant: req.params.id}).exec();

    res.render('restaurant', {  
        user: req.user,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        current_restaurant: current_restaurant,
        products: products
    });
});
```

Comment: try/catch is the way to catch errors when using async/await - most decent documentation/tutorials will show that, e.g [MDN code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Rewriting_a_promise_chain_with_an_async_function)

Comment: I know that at the end it's voting, but can people show a little bit of restraint with the close votes? A lot of questions I see lately have a close vote for no reason at all (or at least not for the one they chose)

Comment: it's certainly not too broad, but the OP could have at least shown that he/she knew about try/catch, considering all examples of error handling with async/await use them. that makes the question poorly researched. If that WAS included in the question, this would likely be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
try {
    var current_restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({restaurantId: req.params.id}).exec();
    var products = await Product.find({restaurant: req.params.id}).exec();

    res.render('restaurant', {  
        user: req.user,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        current_restaurant: current_restaurant,
        products: products
    });
} catch (err) {
    // Handle your errors here...
}
```

which is your typical pattern. Depending on if you can recover and continue with the rendering (with a default value or something), you might want to enclose only the await calls in the try block (and declare the variables before the try block).

Otherwise, you're awaiting promises, so you can still use the promise `.catch` method if that seems cleaner to you.

```
var current_restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({restaurantId: req.params.id}).exec()
    .catch(err => { /* handle error here*/ });
var products = await Product.find({restaurant: req.params.id}).exec()
    .catch(err => { /* handle error here*/ });
```

However, this pattern is only going to be useful if you can still return something valid in your catch code (eg, some kind of default or fallback value). If you need to bail out of the whole thing in the event of an error, this won't work for you, and you should use the previously mentioned `try/catch` pattern instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `await`, then you would use try/catch to catch a rejection of either of the promises you were awaiting:

```
router.get('/restaurant/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let current_restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({restaurantId: req.params.id}).exec();
        let products = await Product.find({restaurant: req.params.id}).exec();
        res.render('restaurant', {  
            user: req.user,
            csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
            current_restaurant: current_restaurant,
            products: products
        });
     } catch(e) {
         // do whatever you want 
         console.log(e);
         res.sendStatus(500);
     }
});
```

You can compare that to regular promise programming using `.then()`:

```
router.get('/restaurant/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.all([
        Restaurant.findOne({restaurantId: req.params.id}).exec(),
        Product.find({restaurant: req.params.id}).exec()
    ]).then([current_restaurant, products] => {
        res.render('restaurant', {  
            user: req.user,
            csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
            current_restaurant: current_restaurant,
            products: products
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        // add your desired error handling here
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Since your two database requests are independent of one another, the second version allows the DB queries to be parallelized and may actually run slightly faster (depends upon your database).